# Divide header from a file and convert that to columns with sequence number including file number in Unix

Tags: unix

My input file is `allresponses_11.txt` which consists of data with headers:

```
ID NAME LOC PH
T1 BA KA 99
T2 GT HS 98
```

I want output as follows.

```
seq_num file_num hname
1 11 ID
2 11 NAME
3 11 LOC
4 11 PH
```

Please help me to get desired output in unix. File names need to pass dynamically.

With the help of you I made script as follows but it is giving output for header as for each word. My headers are divided by tab and has spaces inside header.

```
#!/bin/ksh

export INFAHOME=/informat/PowerCenter/9.1.0/server/infa_shared
export SRCDIR=${INFAHOME}/SrcFiles/CSI/INCOMING
export filename=${SRCDIR}/AllResponses_11003_6_7_20132_17_33AM1.txt
export filenum=$(echo $filename | tr -dc 0-9 |cut -c 1-5)

echo seq_num file_num hname

cnt=1
for h in $(head -1 "$filename")
do
    echo $cnt $filenum $h
    cnt=$((cnt+1))
done
```

My output should be

```
SEQ_NUM  FILE_NUM  HNAME
1  11003  TOTAL COUNT
2  11003  FINAL DAY
3  11003  LADT COUNT
```

My source file delimiter is tab but my header column names have spaces.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what "file number" (the "11"s in your example) mean?

Comment: You don't need any of the export statements for the script to work.  You've not shown the data for the second example output.  Should the header line names be in lower-case (`seq_num` etc) or upper-case (`SEQ_NUM` etc)?

Answer (score 1):

Your file dating convention in:

```
export filename=${SRCDIR}/AllResponses_11003_6_7_20132_17_33AM1.txt
```

is horrendous.  It would make a lot of your life easier if you use a notation such as:

```
filename=${SRCDIR}/AllResponses_11003_2013_06_07_02_17_33_1.txt
```

or a more compact notation such as:

```
filename=${SRCDIR}/AllResponses_11003_20130607_021733_1.txt
```

However, that's tangential to the discussion on hand.  Note that you don't need to export every variable under the sun — in this script, none of the exported variables self-evidently needs to be exported.

Your path name:

```
export INFAHOME=/informat/PowerCenter/9.1.0/server/infa_shared
```

contains three digits which you've not accounted for in your code to extract the file's sequence number.

---

I would probably use `awk` to process the data as you require, using a variation on a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

INFAHOME=/informat/PowerCenter/9.1.0/server/infa_shared
SRCDIR=${INFAHOME}/SrcFiles/CSI/INCOMING
filename=${SRCDIR}/AllResponses_11003_6_7_20132_17_33AM1.txt
filenum=$(basename $filename | sed 's/^[^_]*_\([0-9][0-9]*\)_.*/\1/')

echo seq_num file_num hname

sed 1q "$filename" |    
awk -F $'\t' -v filenum=$filenum '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) print i, filenum, $i;}'
```

I've 'switched shell' to `bash` to allow the use of the `$'\t'` to embed a tab into the `awk` command line.  You can perfectly well use `ksh` instead and replace that with a single quote, a tab, and another single quote, but it is hard to make the space vs tab distinction in SO Markdown.

The assignment to `filenum` uses `basename` to get just the file name.  A `bash` afficionado would write `${filename##*/}` instead; that would probably work in `ksh` too.  The subsequent `sed` command captures a string of digits surrounded by underscores after a series of non-underscores.

The `awk` command uses the tab as the input field separator, thus handling tab-separated blank-containing title elements.

Given a data file such as:

```
TOTAL COUNT     FINAL DAY       LADT COUNT
100     Friday  102
```

(where each sequence of more than one blank is a tab in the data file), and `filenum=11003`, the output is:

```
seq_num file_num hname
1 11003 TOTAL COUNT
2 11003 FINAL DAY
3 11003 LADT COUNT
```

If you want tab-separated output columns too, then add `OFS="\t";` to the `awk` script:

```
awk -F$'\t' -v filenum=11003 '{ OFS="\t"; for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) print i, filenum, $i;}'
1       11003   TOTAL COUNT
2       11003   FINAL DAY
3       11003   LADT COUNT
```

The `sed 1q` command isn't strictly necessary.  You could have `awk` ignore all except the first line of input:

```
awk -F $'\t' -v filenum=$filenum 'NR==1 { for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
                                              print i, filenum, $i;
                                        }'
```

You could get `awk` to print the headings if you wanted to; that might have merit if they needed to be tab-separated.

Answer (score 0):

Although your question is a little lacking in details, I think this might at least approach what you are wanting:

```
filename=allresponses_11.txt
filenum=$(echo ${filename} | tr -dc 0-9)
echo "seq_num file_num hname"
for h in $(head -1 ${filename})
do
  echo "${filenum} ${h}"
done | cat -n
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk to get your answer

awk -F $'\t' -v filenum=$filenum '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) print i, filenum, $i;}'